# Akka equivalent to Java's ObjectInputStream

Tags: java, tcp, deserialization, akka

So I have an acpplication where I'm trying to receive an object (let's call it an `Envelope`) from an external application, serialized over a regular old TCP socket via an `ObjectOuputStream`, on a server that is implemented in Akka. I've set up my server actors very similar to the [Akka TCP tutorial](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/java/io-tcp.html); Below is the relevent implementation of my TCP message handler:

```
public class TcpEnvelopeHandler extends UntypedActor {

    // implementaiton details

    @Override
    public void onReceive( Object message) throws Exception {

        if (message instanceof Received) {
            deserializeEnvelope( (Received) message);
        } // More cases not relevent

    }

    public void deserializeEnvelope( Received message) throws Exception {

        final ObjectInputStream dataStream = new ObjectInputStream( message.data().iterator().asInputStream() );
        final Envelope envelope            = (Envelope) dataStream.readUnshared();
        // Do some stuff with envelope
    }

}
```

Everything works in terms of establishing connections, however as soon as I attempt to deserialize the data I immediately get either `java.io.EOFException` (from the `readUnshared`) or `java.io.StreamCorruptedException` (from the `ObjectInputStream`).

Based on examing the raw `Received` data and the fact that for every one object sent from the client, the Handler is receiving 3 `Received` messages, it's very clear that Akka is just sending me the raw packets rather than framing them properly for deserialization. This makes sense, since that's the job of `ObjectInputStream` in a standard Java client/server model and it's blocking, and Akka isn't big on blocking.

My question is, are there any standard Akka features/actors that mimic the functionality of an `ObjectInputStream` when regestered as a handler to the Tcp manager? Or do I really have to manually implement the packet merging myself? If so, how would I go about doing that?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You should look into Akka Streams.  It's a Reactive Streams implementation built on top of the more lower level Akka IO stuff that you are interacting with.  It will make things much easier for you: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/1.0-M3/scala.html?_ga=1.176770784.498900459.1411518540

Comment: @cmbaxter That seems like it may solve the problem (thought it seems a bit heavy, in that it's really meant for *much* larger objects then I'm dealing with), but it's in a beta version of the library it seems. If at all possible, I'd like to stick to stuff contained in stable milestone releases, as integrating experimental relesaes (and keeping them updated) is a very non-trivial thing in the codebase I'm working with.

Comment: Akka Streams is not going away even though it's marked as experimental.  They are already at an M3 for the 1.0 release and most of the complete API refactors have already happened.  This is pretty stable stuff at this point and they are not going to end of life it.  I also disagree that it's for larger objects.  Not sure why you are saying that.

Comment: @cmbaxter I meant in terms of the original design goal, based on my cursory reading of the API; obviously it works just as well for smaller objects. With respect to its experimental-ness, the point is that this will go into a production code-base where version changes are non-trivial, especially for third-party dependencies. It will be very hard to convince the powers that be to include a dependency that is not in a release form. Regardless of API stability. If there was a fixed release target in the next few months that might be a different story.

Comment: @cmbaxter Actually, and even then, reading more through it, while Streams makes defining flow-based actor graphs a lot easier, it still doesn't explicitly handle the problem of actually doing the packet joining/deserialization step (unless I missed something in the docs). I'd still have to know how to detect a Java serialized object inside the packet stream.

Comment: If the code on the other side is using an object output stream then there should be a natural delimiter in the data to look for. Once you have that things are pretty easy.  Look at the 'Parsing lines from a stream of ByteStrings' part of the Streams Cookbook section. Once you push the full set of bytes for an object to the next processing stage (probably via `map`) you can deserialize the object.

Comment: @cmbaxter) Sadly, Java's serialization method [doesn't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2072752/the-java-serialization-algorithm-revealed.html). While there is a magic-number the delineates the start of an object, there is no magic number end-of-object, the size of the serialized data is contained recursively throughout the serialized stream. Perhaps figuring out a way to place a `TypedActor` inside the ObjectOutputStream that offers the expected `OutputStream` interface would be easier. I was hoping Akka just had something for this since they  clearly serialize to remote actors.

Comment: The latest news on the API stabilizing: https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/akka-user/fkDlvjY8Jmw